# Dropdown Menu Hiding Behind Picture

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu and a main photo on the index.html of my website. However, when I hover over the dropdown menu, it hides behind the main photo and can be slightly seen only if the window is resized.

Here is the link to my website:
[wanghenry79.github.io](https://wanghenry79.github.io)

The dropdown menu hidden behind the main photo should be seen when hovering over the "Resources" tab.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: You need to adjust z-index (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) [See print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEUCA.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `.newest-review-cover` just remove the `position: relative`;

```
.newest-review-cover {
    position: relative; // REMOVE THIS LINE
    z-index: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

or give `av ul li:hover ul` a z index:

```
av ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the dropdown has a lower z-index than the image's z-index.

Add this to the dropdown menu `<ul>`:

`style="z-index: 9;"`